# network error (Tcp error)

Tags: tcp, hadoop

I am inside a network where I need proxy settings to access the internet.
I have a weird problem.

The internet is working fine.
But it is one particular instance when i get this error:

```
Network Error (tcp_error) 

A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team.
```

This happens when I use hadoop in local mode.
I can access the UI interface. I can see the jobs running. but when I try to see the logs of each task.. i am not able to access those logs.

```
UI--> job-->map--> task--> all <-- this is where the error is..
```

Any clues?
THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about exactly what your tcp action is, or about Hadoop or your proxy setup, but if you can reliably repeat the error, and the timeout error happens at approximately the same time each time you test, and that time is on the order of minutes, my guess would be that you've got a true processing delay (perhaps caused by blocking somewhere) at the server, but not necessarily.